# Hausdorff compactly generated is locally compact?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I was trying to prove the "theorem of exponential correspondence" and "exponential law" with $X,Y,Z$ compactly generated and Hausdorff.

According to *Hedwin H.Spanier-Algebraic Topology* and Tammo tom Dieck-Algebraic topology we have that locally compact seems necessary in order to prove the statement.

The true hyphotesis given on the spaces are Hausdorff locally compact, but as far as I can see, compactly generated and Hausdorff doesn't imply locally compact, am I right ? Are my hypothesis wrong ? Are there any counterexample.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, if the exponential law holds for a space (in the compact-open topology), it implies it's locally compact Hausdorff. So it's indeed necessary; this has been known since the 1950's I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple example would be $\Bbb Q$, endowed with its usual topology. It is metrizable, and therefore compactly generated. But it is not locally compact.

Answer (score 3):

You can take any non-locally compact metric space, for some familiar examples. E.g., the Baire space $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.